# puppetserver 7.11 is crashing after installing activerecord-jdbc-adapter gem

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, puppet, jruby

I have a test puppetserver 7.11 in the running status.
I want to write custom function with active_record and sqlite3 interface to pull data from the database for catalog generation.

When i install activerecord-jdbc-adapter gem (with lot of dependence) my puppetserver is not starting anymore (I have tested it 2 times from the scratch installation).

`puppetserver gem install activerecord-jdbc-adapter`

Here what I can see in the puppetserver.log file:

```
2023-06-02T09:30:00.920-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.s.scheduler-service] Initializing Scheduler Service
2023-06-02T09:30:00.971-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2023-06-02T09:30:00.994-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.c.SchedulerSignalerImpl] Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerS
ignalerImpl
2023-06-02T09:30:00.995-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2023-06-02T09:30:00.996-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.s.RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
2023-06-02T09:30:00.998-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'b5b3f60b-bdde-47d0-8607-82d3690
5b4c4' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2023-06-02T09:30:00.998-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'b5b3f60b-bdde-47d0-8607-82d36905b4c4' initialized from an
 externally provided properties instance.
2023-06-02T09:30:00.998-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2023-06-02T09:30:00.998-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Scheduler b5b3f60b-bdde-47d0-8607-82d36905b4c4_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2023-06-02T09:30:01.003-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.w.jetty9-service] Initializing web server(s).
2023-06-02T09:30:01.086-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.s.status-service] Registering status callback function for service 'puppet-profiler', version 7.
11.0
2023-06-02T09:30:01.090-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.j.jruby-puppet-service] Initializing the JRuby service
2023-06-02T09:30:01.126-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.j.jruby-pool-manager-service] Initializing the JRuby service
2023-06-02T09:30:01.144-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.j.jruby-puppet-service] JRuby version info: jruby 9.3.9.0 (2.6.8) 2022-10-24 537cd1f8bc OpenJDK 64
-Bit Server VM 25.372-b07 on 1.8.0_372-b07 +jit [x86_64-linux]
2023-06-02T09:30:01.216-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.s.status-service] Registering status callback function for service 'jruby-metrics', version 7.11
.0
2023-06-02T09:30:01.231-04:00 INFO  [clojure-agent-send-pool-0] [p.s.j.i.jruby-internal] Creating JRubyInstance with id 1.
2023-06-02T09:30:01.248-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.v.versioned-code-service] No code-id-command set for versioned-code-service. Code-id will be nil.
2023-06-02T09:30:01.249-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.s.v.versioned-code-service] No code-content-command set for versioned-code-service. Attempting to fe
tch code content will fail.
2023-06-02T09:30:01.272-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.s.m.jolokia] Metrics access control using trapperkeeper-authorization is enabled.
2023-06-02T09:30:16.710-04:00 ERROR [clojure-agent-send-pool-0] [p.t.internal] shutdown-on-error triggered because of exception!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There was a problem adding a JRubyInstance to the pool.
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34540$add_instance__34545$fn__34549.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:58)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34540$add_instance__34545.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:47)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34567$prime_pool_BANG___34572$fn__34576.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:76)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34567$prime_pool_BANG___34572.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:61)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35129$fn__35130.invoke(instance_pool.clj:16)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:403)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:388)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15141$shutdown_service__15146$fn$reify__15148$service_fnk__5324__auto___positional$reify__15153.shutdown_on_e
rror(internal.clj:448)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15088$G__15067__15096.invoke(internal.clj:411)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15088$G__15066__15105.invoke(internal.clj:411)
        at clojure.core$partial$fn__5908.invoke(core.clj:2642)
        at clojure.core$partial$fn__5908.invoke(core.clj:2641)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34514$send_agent__34519$fn__34520$agent_fn__34521.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:41)
        at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__5823.invoke(core.clj:2050)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.doRun(Agent.java:114)
        at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.run(Agent.java:163)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (NameError) uninitialized constant Concurrent::RubyThreadLocalVar
        at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:134)
        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1296)
        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1289)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:167)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:102)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby.jruby_puppet_core$fn__36348$get_initialize_pool_instance_fn__36353$fn__36354$fn__36355.invoke(jruby_puppet_core.clj:115)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34122$create_pool_instance_BANG___34131$fn__34134.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:256)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34122$create_pool_instance_BANG___34131.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:225)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34540$add_instance__34545$fn__34549.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:52)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.NameError: (NameError) uninitialized constant Concurrent::RubyThreadLocalVar
        at org.jruby.RubyModule.const_missing(org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3947)
        at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/thread_local.rb:6)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
        at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
        at RUBY.<module:Puppet>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:44)
        at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:41)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
        at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
        at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server/master.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
        at RUBY.<main>(<script>:1)
2023-06-02T09:30:16.735-04:00 ERROR [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.internal] Error during service init!!!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to borrow JRubyInstance from pool
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34322$borrow_from_pool_BANG__STAR___34327$fn__34328.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:313)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34322$borrow_from_pool_BANG__STAR___34327.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:300)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34369$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__34374$fn__34375.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:348)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34369$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__34374.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:337)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35133.invokeStatic(instance_pool.clj:48)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35133.invoke(instance_pool.clj:10)
        at puppetlabs.services.protocols.jruby_pool$fn__34923$G__34871__34930.invoke(jruby_pool.clj:3)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__36047$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__36052$fn__36053.invoke(jruby_core.clj:222)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__36047$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__36052.invoke(jruby_core.clj:209)
        at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__44146$get_puppet_config__44151$fn__44152$fn__44153.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:10
6)
        at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__44146$get_puppet_config__44151$fn__44152.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:106)
        at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__44146$get_puppet_config__44151.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:101)
        at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_service$reify__44181$service_fnk__5324__auto___positional$reify__44192.init(puppet_server_config_se
rvice.clj:25)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$fn__5148$G__5140__5151.invoke(services.clj:9)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$fn__5148$G__5139__5155.invoke(services.clj:9)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14623$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___14630$fn__14631.invoke(internal.clj:196)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14623$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___14630.invoke(internal.clj:179)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14652$run_lifecycle_fns__14657$fn__14658.invoke(internal.clj:229)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14652$run_lifecycle_fns__14657.invoke(internal.clj:206)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15278$build_app_STAR___15287$fn$reify__15299.init(internal.clj:614)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15328$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15335$fn__15336$fn__15338.invoke(internal.clj:648)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15328$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15335$fn__15336.invoke(internal.clj:647)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15328$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15335.invoke(internal.clj:641)
        at clojure.core$partial$fn__5910.invoke(core.clj:2647)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14697$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14708$fn__14709$fn__14872$state_machine__11931__auto____14897$fn__14900.in
voke(internal.clj:249)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14697$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14708$fn__14709$fn__14872$state_machine__11931__auto____14897.invoke(inter
nal.clj:249)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:978)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:977)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:982)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:980)
        at clojure.core.async$ioc_alts_BANG_$fn__12160.invoke(async.clj:421)
        at clojure.core.async$do_alts$fn__12099$fn__12102.invoke(async.clj:288)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__6772$fn__6773.invoke(channels.clj:99)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.concurrent$counted_thread_factory$reify__6675$fn__6676.invoke(concurrent.clj:29)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (NameError) uninitialized constant Concurrent::RubyThreadLocalVar
        at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:134)
        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1296)
        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1289)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:167)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:102)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby.jruby_puppet_core$fn__36348$get_initialize_pool_instance_fn__36353$fn__36354$fn__36355.invoke(jruby_puppet_core.clj:115)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34122$create_pool_instance_BANG___34131$fn__34134.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:256)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34122$create_pool_instance_BANG___34131.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:225)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34540$add_instance__34545$fn__34549.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:52)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34540$add_instance__34545.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:47)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34567$prime_pool_BANG___34572$fn__34576.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:76)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34567$prime_pool_BANG___34572.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:61)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35129$fn__35130.invoke(instance_pool.clj:16)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:403)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:388)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15141$shutdown_service__15146$fn$reify__15148$service_fnk__5324__auto___positional$reify__15153.shutdown_on_e
rror(internal.clj:448)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15088$G__15067__15096.invoke(internal.clj:411)
        at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15088$G__15066__15105.invoke(internal.clj:411)
        at clojure.core$partial$fn__5908.invoke(core.clj:2642)
        at clojure.core$partial$fn__5908.invoke(core.clj:2641)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34514$send_agent__34519$fn__34520$agent_fn__34521.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:41)
        at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__5823.invoke(core.clj:2050)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.doRun(Agent.java:114)
        at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.run(Agent.java:163)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.NameError: (NameError) uninitialized constant Concurrent::RubyThreadLocalVar
        at org.jruby.RubyModule.const_missing(org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3947)
        at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/thread_local.rb:6)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
        at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require_relative(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045)
        at RUBY.<module:Puppet>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:44)
        at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:41)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
      at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
        at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
        at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server/master.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017)
        at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85)
        at RUBY.<main>(<script>:1)
2023-06-02T09:30:16.751-04:00 INFO  [main] [p.t.internal] Beginning shutdown sequence
2023-06-02T09:30:16.774-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-3] [p.s.j.jruby-metrics-service] JRuby Metrics Service: stopping metrics sampler job
2023-06-02T09:30:16.775-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-3] [p.s.j.jruby-metrics-service] JRuby Metrics Service: stopped metrics sampler job
2023-06-02T09:30:16.783-04:00 INFO  [async-dispatch-3] [p.s.j.i.jruby-agents] Draining JRuby pool.
2023-06-02T09:30:16.796-04:00 ERROR [async-dispatch-3] [p.t.internal] Encountered error during shutdown sequence
java.lang.InterruptedException: Lock can't be granted because a pill has been inserted
        at com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.pool.JRubyPool.lockWithTimeout(JRubyPool.java:368)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:167)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:102)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34648$borrow_all_jrubies__34653$fn__34654$fn__34655.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:128)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34648$borrow_all_jrubies__34653$fn__34654.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:127)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34648$borrow_all_jrubies__34653.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:119)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34728$drain_and_refill_pool_BANG___34737$fn__34740.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:190)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34728$drain_and_refill_pool_BANG___34737.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:172)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34769$flush_pool_for_shutdown_BANG___34774$fn__34775.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:211)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34769$flush_pool_for_shutdown_BANG___34774.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:199)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35145.invokeStatic(instance_pool.clj:20)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__35145.invoke(instance_pool.clj:10)
        at puppetlabs.services.protocols.jruby_pool$fn__34999$G__34883__35004.invoke(jruby_pool.clj:3)
        at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__36122$flush_pool_for_shutdown_BANG___36127$fn__36128.invoke(jruby_core.c
```

Comment: The original exception is `org.jruby.exceptions.NameError: (NameError) uninitialized constant Concurrent::RubyThreadLocalVar`.  It's hard to say specifically why that arises, but generally speaking, it's probably because of an incompatible combination of gem versions.  `Concurrent` is involved, but so is at least one other module that is trying to use `Concurrent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @John, you pointed me into the right direction.

I figured out that last version of `activerecord-jdbc-adapter -v 61.2` installs `concurrent-ruby -v 1.2.2` additionally to `-v 1.1.5`. Which cause exception above. Uninstalling any of this version afterwards does not resolve problem.

But I was resolve it with `activerecord-jdbc-adapter -v 61.1` which has dependency to `concurrent-ruby -v 1.1.5`.

By some reason it still installed `-v 1.2.2` along with the previous version, which I had to uninstall manually before starting puppetserver.

```
[root@puppet-server ~]# puppetserver gem install activerecord-jdbc-adapter -v 61.1
[root@puppet-server ~]# puppetserver gem uninstall concurrent-ruby -v 1.2.2
[root@puppet-server ~]# systemctl start puppetserver
[root@puppet-server ~]# systemctl status puppetserver
● puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-06-02 09:23:54 EDT; 5s ago
```